# 'REACT_APP_SERVER' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: reactjs

Thanks for the help in advance. I am trying to install a react app but it is not installing.I am using yarn for this.
The screenshot of the error I am getting after yarn install is the below one[image]

the error I am getting after yarn run start is 'REACT_APP_SERVER' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "queenofraw",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://ja.materiamx.com",
  "main": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.3.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.3.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.0.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "@mdi/svg": "^3.0.39",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.3",
    "@react-jvectormap/core": "^1.0.3",
    "@rematch/core": "^0.6.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.8.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "antd": "^3.10.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "country-list": "^2.1.0",
    "echarts": "^4.2.0-rc.2",
    "echarts-for-react": "^2.0.15-beta.0",
    "err": "^2.1.12",
    "events": "^2.0.0",
    "formsy-react": "^1.1.4",
    "image-to-base64": "^2.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "loadash": "^1.0.0",
    "material-ui-table-edit": "^3.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.22.0",
    "namor": "^1.1.1",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "query-parse": "^2.0.0",
    "rc-queue-anim": "^1.6.7",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1",
    "react-confirm": "^0.1.17",
    "react-cookie": "^3.0.4",
    "react-country-flag": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^7.0.1",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.2.2",
    "react-images-upload": "^1.2.3",
    "react-inline-editing": "^1.0.10",
    "react-jvectormap": "0.0.4",
    "react-moment": "^0.8.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.11",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6",
    "recharts": "^1.2.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "socket.io-client": "1.7.0",
    "superagent": "^4.0.0-beta.5",
    "web-vitals": "^3.0.1",
    "yarn": "^1.13.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "REACT_APP_SERVER=https://api-dev.materiamx.com react-scripts start",
    "starts": "PORT=6500 REACT_APP_SERVER=http://localhost:5080  react-scripts start",
    "sass:watch": "node-sass -w src/assets/scss/style.scss -o src/assets/css",
    "sass:build": "node-sass src/assets/scss/style.scss -o src/assets/css --source-map true",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel start sass:watch",
    "start:stag": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "REACT_APP_SERVER=http://192.168.2.18:5080 react-scripts build",
    "deploy": "aws s3 sync build/ s3://qor-mmx-static --acl public-read",
    "stag:build": "REACT_APP_SERVER=https://api-dev.materiamx.com react-scripts build",
    "prod:build": "REACT_APP_SERVER=https://api-dev.materiamx.com/ react-scripts build",
    "stag": "yarn run stag:build && sls client deploy --stage staging --aws-profile qor --region us-east-1",
    "prod": "yarn run prod:build && sls client deploy --stage production --aws-profile qor --region us-east-1",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.68.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "react-edit-inline": "^1.0.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
    "serverless-finch": "^2.2.0",
    "serverless-single-page-app-plugin": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {}
}
```

Comment: It won't work on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows doesn't support setting env variables like that

I would recommend using [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

1. Install `npm install -D cross-env`
2. Change your commands to `cross-env REACT_APP_SERVER=https://api-dev.materiamx.com react-scripts start"`

You can also try using git bash instead, but I doubt it will work

Comment: thanks for help...tried but not working

Answer (score -1):

You should install python2.7 and Visual studio 2019 Environment.

[Python 2.7 download link](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2716/)

I wish your success.

Comment: thanks for help...tried but not working

Comment: can you upload screenshot for console after install python 2.7?